# ListView not showing default view

Tags: android, android-listview

I have included a List View into my android application. However when I added it and gave it a id (listView) the List View was blank on the application unlike what I have seen on the internet.

My View:
[My View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcC2X.png)

The normal View:
[Normal View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0SD3.png)

Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java file:

```
package com.example.applicationv1;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Logs extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.logs);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
}

}
```

Why cannot I view the view that other people have like in the normal view above?

Answer (score 0):

You already have normal `View`, there is a list and it is empty. you have to make some [Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter) for producing list items. [Here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-from-scratch-understanding-adapters-and-adapter-views--cms-26646) and [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) you have some nice examples, there is also plenty of them if you use web search

Comment: No, the listview was suppose to populate with the normal view as shown in the pic, even without using the adapter. This was shown in other youtube videos. All they did was add a list view and after they gave it an id the list view changed from blank to the normal view picture without adding the adapter.

Comment: so the were laying to you, there is no content in any `View` in android, you have to set it. for `TextView` is just `setText` method, for `ListView` you have adapters. without adapter there won't be a single item on list, never